# Subnetting IPv6 in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5, and I was wondering if postgres allows for any type of subnetting or calculations on IP addresses, specifically IPv6. I am aware they have the `cidr`[format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) for storing data like IpV4 and Ipv6 formats. However, can I do anything like find out how many client IP's are in the subnet stored in the DB?

For example. If I stored the IPv6 address of `2001:dd8::/64`, could I find out how many host IPs there are (18446744073709551616, according to some calculators).

My guess is that the answer is NO, postgres does not support this.

Answer (score 5):

As 3manuek [mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149999/6219), there *are* functions and operators to deal with IP addresses - be it IPv4 or IPv6.

I am wondering a bit where your number comes from.  The address range you gave translates to

```
2001:0dd8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

which is an address range of length 1.

If you meant all possible addresses starting with '2001:dd8:', then the correct designation of this range would be `2001:dd8::/32`, as it is the first 32 bits that are given.  According to a [calculator tool](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=2001%3Add8%3A%3A%2F32), the resulting range is the following:

```
Start Range: 2001:dd8:0:0:0:0:0:0
End Range: 2001:dd8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
No. of host: 79228162514264337593543950336
```

Meanwhile, if you omit the block size (`/32`), you get a single address (the one I showed above).

So, there is a way to get the number provided by the calculator, using builtin PostgreSQL functionality.  Our friend here is `masklen()`:

```
SELECT round(2 ^ (128 - masklen('2001:dd8::/32'::cidr))::numeric);

             round             
───────────────────────────────
 79228162514264337593543950336
```

The result is the same as form the calculator.  The rounding is there for removing the decimal point and the zeros after it, which are the result of casting to `numeric`.

Comment: Would you still need to use `round` if you cast the result to `numeric(30,0)`?

Comment: @AndriyM Casting to `numeric(39,0)` could be a solution, yes.

Comment: @dezso, yes I omitted the subnet mask `/32` or `/64`

Answer (score 1):

Well, Postgres supports [Network Operators and Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-net.html) and IPv6 isn't the exception. Actually your question is a good one, as I didn't see much examples around on how to do this (explicitly with IPv6). Here is an example on how you can do that:

```
postgres=# SELECT '2001:0DD8::1428:57AB/128'::cidr <<   
           '2001:dd8::/32'::inet;
----------
  t
```

The `<<` operator corresponds to the *is contained by*. The above example does only the inline comparison, but it can be used as an usual operator like in the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM IPv6s WHERE theIp << '2001:dd8::/32'::cidr;
```

I made an small example at this [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d790/3).